# Assign value of subquery inside a CASE expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, plpgsql

I want to get a value if it exists, if it doesn't exist I want to return a random number (it's a bit more complicated than that but that's the essence of it).

My query I think would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    something, 
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT column_1 FROM table_1 WHERE something)  
            THEN column_1
            ELSE RANDOM()
    END;
```

which is not valid obviously.

I use Postgresql and I am inside a plpgsql function.

What should I do?

Comment: If you want to return the value of Column_1 you need to outer join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

using [COALESCE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-coalesce/) I can do this:

```
SELECT something, CΟALESCE((SELECT column_1 FROM table_1 WHERE something), RANDOM())
```

When the first query does not return something, RANDOM takes the lead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the column from an `EXISTS` condition as that only yields true or false. The SELECTed columns from the subquery are completely ignored as well.

So you need to repeat the SELECT in the THEN part to get the column value:

```
SELECT 'something' as one_column, 
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                      FROM table_1 
                      WHERE <some_condition>) 
           THEN (select column_1 from table_1 where <some_condition>)
         ELSE random()
       END as other_column;
```

Note the parentheses around the SELECT in the THEN branch. They are necessary to mark this as a scalar query. You also need to make sure that `some_condition` only returns a single row

Comment: I didn't want to reuse the expression as it's quite expensive. I learned about COALESCE though, and it gets the job done. You can see my answer.